# Jersey on google app engine

Tags: java, api, google-app-engine, rest, jersey

We have an AppEngine app with that we would like to use with Google Endpoints. We need to support mobile clients so is it necessary to use jersey framework for developing backend API's?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use Jersey. Cloud Endpoints come with their own client library for [Android](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android), [iOS](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios) and [Javascript](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js).